# How to run Android Virtual Device in WebStorm

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, webstorm

I've started react native programming recently, I use WebStorm for coding, I always have to run Android Studio and start my Android Virtual Device and then Close Android Studio and work with WebStorm and run and test my react native app.

how can I run my Android Virtual Device from webstorm without the need to open Android Studio?

Comment: You can start your vd's from your terminal using emulator @devicename

Comment: is there any way to run it from webstorm ide ? because both of android studio and webstorm based on intellij

Comment: you can use this command: "cd /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/tools && ./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_24", just replace the path and name of your AVD

Comment: simply define that as an `external command` (which may even include building, packaging and installing the `APK`)... this is fully script-able.

Comment: How can i do it. What parameters should i set at external command page to do it? Have you ever do it? @MartinZeitler

Comment: @danialjn this depends if you are on Linux or Windows (or even Mac). passing a script file is most easy, because alike this, one has multiple lines, which one can conveniently edit with the IDE.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I am on windows. I checked external tools windows it needs some parameters not file!

Comment: @danialjn answered with a screenshot; where `Program` refers to an `executable file`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***solution***

Finally, with the help of "*Martin Zeitler*", I succeeded in doing this in the following way:

In webstorm select File>settings, in search bar type "External Tools" select "External Tools", in "tools" section click on plus icon (add) fill this window like my parameter:

Name: android avd

*as you like

Program: C:\Users(your user name)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe

*this is your emulator.exe address and this is the default address, you have to replace (your user name) with your system user name or change the address for locating to your emulator.exe address

Arguments: -avd Nexus_5X_API_23

*Nexus_5X_API_23 is a sample you have to type your emulator name that you create it before in android studio

Working directory: C:\Users(your user name)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator

*like Program address but without emulator.exe

click ok

now in webstorm in tools menu in External Tools section you can find android avd or your custom name. by click on it you can run your emulator from webstorm.

finally you don't need android studio at all , you can run it from webstorm.

Answer (score 4):

it might be easier to explain with a screenshot ...

except that for Windows™ you'd have to use a `.bat` batch script, instead of `.sh` shell script

[image: IDE screenshot]

the shell script, which is being used in the example, can be found [here](https://github.com/syslogic/bash-scripts/blob/master/wrap_android_emulator.sh).

it does a little more than just start the emulator and is for Linux only.

(just to provide an idea, what can be done in the given situation).

here it is explained: 
[Start the emulator from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline).

Comment: thanks, wrap_android_emulator.sh file is very complicated but i try to do it on windows in webstorm

Comment: @danialjn as stated, this is just an example (and even obsolete, because meanwhile one can do this with Android Studio); it could as well as just contain `%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\tools\emulator.exe -avd @Pixel_XL_API_28` ...or `%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\tools\emulator.exe` as the `Program` with `-avd @Pixel_XL_API_28` as the `Arguments` being passed.

Comment: thanks, i do it and add the solution to the main post with your name.

Comment: @danialjn there is no need to; up-voting and/or accepting the answer does already suffice. in case it differs much from what I've suggested, you could post your own Windows-specific answer.... please don't put answers into questions.

Comment: i change in and i put it in new Windows-specific answer

Answer (score -1):

No, WebStorm provides no Android support and there are no plugins you can use to run android virtual devices within Webstorm.

Although you can run android emulator from terminal without using Android studio.
For example on Windows, you can use the following from the command prompt:

```
 start "" C:\Users\qasim\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe @Pixel_XL_API_28
```

Comment: @JNDanial 's answer worked for me so.. yeah, it is possible :)